# Parsing the calling of a function without an argument in the parameters of a function - FParsec

Tags: f#, fparsec

I'm trying to implement an analyzer via a monadic parser combination using FParsec. I also use an indentation module, but it is not important for the current problem.

So I'm trying to parse this branch of my little AST:

```
type Identifier = string

type Expression =
    ...
    | Call of Identifier * Expression list
    ...
type Program = Program of Expression list
```

I have this implementation:

```
// Identifier parser
let private identifier =
    many1Satisfy2L isLetter
        (fun c -> isLetter c || isDigit c) "identifier"

// Monadic parser
let call = parse {
        let! id = identifier
        let! parameters = sepBy parameter spaces1
        return Call(id, parameters)
    }

and expression =
    ... // <|>
    attempt call // <|>
    ...
```

`parameter` represents all acceptable expressions in a function call as a parameter:

```
// All possible parameter
let parameter =
    attempt pint32 <|> // A number, for example.
    attempt (identifier |>> fun callid -> Call(callid, [])) <|>
    attempt (between (pstring "(") (pstring ")") call)
```

As you can see, there are two elements of the parser that use the "C/call". They correspond to this, in order and for example:

```
add x 1  // Call the function `add` and passing it another call (`x`) and the simple literal `1`
add (add 8 2) 10 // Call the function `add` and passing it another call (`add 8 2`) and the simple literal `10`
```

And of course, these elements can also be intertwined:

```
add (add x 1) 7
```

The problem, which I obviously can't solve otherwise I won't ask the question, is that the generated tree doesn't look like what is expected:

`add x 1` gives:

```
Success: Program [Call ("add",[Call ("x",[]); Literal (Int 1)])]
```

In other words, the parser seems to identify the following `x` as the arguments of `x`.

However, the second way works. `add (add 8 2) 10` gives:

```
Success: Program
  [Call
     ("add",[Call ("add",[Literal (Int 8); Literal (Int 2)]); Literal (Int 10)])]
```

Could you put me on track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like the following line matches `x`:

```
attempt (identifier |>> fun callid -> Call(callid, [])) <|>
```

A single identifier is seen as a `call`.

It therefore doesn't suprise that you get: `[Call ("add",[Call ("x",[]); Literal (Int 1)])`

As you think this is wrong what is the expected results for you? I would have expected this to be an identifer dereference expression.

Also a tip, you seem to have opted for the OCaml style of invoking functions like so: `f x y`

Perhaps you should also go for the OCaml style that a function always takes a single argument and returns a single value.

`add x 1` would then be parsed into something like: `Apply (Apply (Identifier "add", Identifier "x"), Literal 1)`